# Rails 4 + Wicked: Using params to route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-gem

I have a bit of a complicated wizard and I'd like to route the user based on their entries to the form.

I have listed the steps as follows:

```
steps :weight_loss_history, :health_conditions, :cancer, :weight_mindset, :diabetes, :diet_information, :heart,  :food_intake
```

...and my update and routing functions are as follows:

```
def update
    @remote = current_remote
    params[:remote][:step] = step
    atts = Remote.fix_attributes(params[:remote])
    @remote.attributes = atts # equal to large hash of params
    find_route(@remote)
end

def find_route(info)
    if info[:cancer]
        puts "cancer..." # I never see this in the console
        jump_to(:cancer)
    else
        render_wizard info
    end
end
```

Does anyone have a good implementation of using Wicked to route users based on their choices?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in an info attribute that you pass into find_route. 
I guess that you have to rewrite your action like that:

```
def update
  @remote = current_remote
  params[:remote][:step] = step
  atts = Remote.fix_attributes(params[:remote])
  @remote.attributes = atts # equal to large hash of params
  return jump_to(:cancer) if step == :cancer
  return render_wizard info
end
```

if you push from step otherwise i guess that @remote doesn't contains :cancer key and if case of using ruby hash you have to set key like that:

```
@remote[:cancer] = true
return jump_to(:cancer) if @remote[:cancer] 
return render_wizard info
```